# Looping a linux command with input and multiple pipes

Tags: linux, loops, input, pipe, tr

This command works, but I want it run it on every document (input.txt) in every subdirectory.

```
tr -d '\n' < input.txt | awk '{gsub(/\. /,".\n");print}' | grep “\[" >> SingleOutput.txt
```

The code takes the file input and divides it into sentences with new lines.  Then it finds all the sentences that contain a “[“ and outputs the sentences to a single file.
I tried several looping techniques with find and for loops, but couldn't get it to run in this example.  I tried

```
for dir in ./*; do 
(cd "$dir" && tr -d '\n' < $dir | awk '{gsub(/\. /,".\n");print}' | grep “\[" >> /home/dan/SingleOutput.txt); 
done;
```

and also

```
find ./ -execdir tr -d '\n' < . | awk '{gsub(/\. /,".\n");print}' | grep "\[" >> /home/dan/SingleOutput.txt;
```

but they didn't work execute just giving me > marks.  any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd $dir
find ./ | grep "input.txt$" | while read file; do tr -d '\n' < $file | awk '{gsub(/\. /,".\n");print}' | grep “\[" >> SingleOutput.txt; done
```

This will find all files called input.txt under $dir, the it will perform what you say it's already working send output to $dir/SingleOutput.txt.

Comment: This did what I wanted without the first grep.  Thank you!

find ./ | while read file; do tr -d '\n' < $file | awk '{gsub(/\. /,".\n");print}' | grep “\[" >> SingleOutput.txt; done

Comment: I am glad it helped. Feel free to accept as correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just something like this?

`tr -d '\n' < */input.txt | awk '{gsub(/\. /,".\n");print}' | grep “\[" >> SingleOutput.txt`

Or are you interested in keeping the output for each `input.txt` separate?